# How do I connect to JawsDB (add-on) with a Github deployment (javascript program) on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, heroku

I have tried my best to debug this issue for the past few days with no luck. I am a beginner so there could totally be simple things I just didn't know. So I have JawsDB as an add-on in Heroku and I can connect to it when running my JS program with the command line. But when Heroku deploys the Github code, it gives me a connection error (screenshot). Could anyone help me out?[Heroku connection error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isBVP.png)

Comment: How are you deploying your code? [Heroku disabled GH deployment functionality in April](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413) due to a security threat. If you're using auto-deploy after a GH push you'll have to switch to the Heroku CLI and deploy manually until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1. Where is your database connection configured? Are you trying to use the environment variable that provides a proper connection string?

Comment: Andy: Yes, I'm using auto-deploy. I will look into CLI manual deployment.

@Chris Thank you, I will avoid posting images in the future. I have tried both using the connection string and passing parameters according to Sequelize documentation. Both methods have worked when running on my machine but not with Heroku's GH deployment. When using the connection string, I pass it as an environment variable. When passing database parameters (host, port, username, etc), I only use the password as an evironment variable. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Update: I believe the issue is what Andy has pointed out. I tried deploying when the entirety of my main function is commented out (so no DB connection code) and it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Heroku's automatic GitHub deployment as Andy pointed out. After testing manual deployment with Heroku CLI, everything works as it should.